# Django says: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using Django. In the `upload_book` function, I generate a 10-digit code for each book and I identify and distinguish two books from one another by their code, rather than their primary key. However, I get an error in the `generate_code` function:

```
ValueError at /main/upload_book/
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here is the `generate_code()` function with required imports:

```
import random, string
def generate_code(max_length):
    code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=max_length))
    while len(Book.objects.filter(code)) != 0:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=max_length))
    return code
```

I did the extra bit over there to prevent two books being of the same code, however low the probability of that might be with 62<sup>9</sup> possible combinations.
And here's my `upload_book()` function:

```
@login_required
def upload_book(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        author = request.POST.get('author')
        code = generate_code(10)
        owner = request.user
        if 'thumbnail' in request.FILES:
            thumbnail = request.FILES['thumbnail']
        book = Book(title=title, description=description, author=author, thumbnail=thumbnail, owner=owner, code=code)
        book.save()
        return redirect("/main/all_books/")
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/upload_book.html')
```

And my `Book` model in `models.py`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='book_thumbnails', blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = IntegerField(default=1)
    min_age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    max_age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10)
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The error is at this line of the `upload_book()` function:

```
code = generate_code(10)
```

Which leads to this line in the `generate_code()` function:

```
while len(Book.objects.filter(code)) != 0:
```

Here's the error with its traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /main/upload_book/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/centel/books/main/views.py", line 101, in upload_book
    code = generate_code(10)
  File "/Users/adithraghav/Documents/Work/centel/books/main/views.py", line 24, in generate_code
    while len(Book.objects.filter(code)) != 0:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1393, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1412, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1283, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I don't know why this is happening. In another question, the accepted answer mentioned that this happens when `split()` is used and that returns more than two elements. I'm joining the elements of the list which is generated by `random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=max_length)` into a string. When I print `''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=max_length))` in the Python IDLE shell, it returns a string all right. So what's the issue here?

Comment: Kindly add full error traceback whenever you ask a question.

Comment: Right-o, edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use filter() method on model objects you have to pass filed name too

So change this line

```
while len(Book.objects.filter(code)) != 0:
```

to

```
while Book.objects.filter(code=code).count() != 0:
```

Comment: you have forgotten the `len()` in your answer and also you can use `.count()` or am i missing something ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, will update the answer.

Comment: Whoa! Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!